# Custom SWT list item

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am developing an application which basically just loads plugins inside a folder. It should list the loaded plugins in a SWT GUI. The items of the list should show more information than just one string. For example it should have one line which displays the plugins name, one line which displays a description and one for the version. How could I extend a SWT control or the JFace ListViewer so that it behaves like this? I did not find any information when searching for "custom swt list item" or similar terms. Is it actually possible?

Comment: Look at `TableViewer` for columns. Multiple lines is also possible with TableViewer but more difficult

Comment: Everything is possible:)

Comment: In addition to previous comments, [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) is an excellent tutorial about `TableViewer`s.

Comment: Thank you so far. Can the TableViewer look like a ListViewer? For example I don't want column labels.

Comment: @feuerball Just call `tableViewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(false);` to hode the column labels.